# Sticky expired film

Tags: film, 35mm, kodak, film-cameras, expired-film

I have recently (*2-3 weeks ago*) bought a lot of expired films and they stayed in my bag since then.

I wanted to use one of them (*color plus 2007/2008*), but the film was very sticky and almost all parts of the film changed their color.

The day on which I bought them was rainy and films were not stored in boxes, but i put them into the empty canisters as soon as possible. (*but other films are normal*)

Can it be because of the water?

Comment: "almost all parts of the film changed their color"... what do you mean exactly? And what do you mean by sticky? What is sticky? I wouldn't put a "sticky" film into my camera!

Comment: By changing color i mean that the chemicals were gone and there were transparent spots on it.İ haven’t put that film into my camera either.(sticky means adhesive/gummy)

Comment: but how do you know the chemicals were gone and the film was transparent? Did you pull it out of its canister? Did you develop it? Are you just talking about the film leader? I am really having trouble understanding your situation.

Comment: Sorry for my bad english.Yes exactly, i pulled it out from its canister.When i wanted to put the new film into my camera, the beginning of the roll had the spots on it so I thought that maybe the rest of the film would be normal.But unfortunately, almost all of the leader was like that.